# Php login form problems

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am having problems with this, when i login with valid data, the page just refreshes (i am assuming that the if statement in protectedstuff.php failed). When i used the deprecated method to register the session and check if it exists, it worked `if(!session_is_registered(myusername))`.

Oh and also I am able to see a cookie was created "PHPSESSID".

what am I doing wrong?

login.php ->

```
<?php
if($_POST){
$errorLogin="Wrong Username or Password";
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '',  'mydb')
        or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];


$sql_query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword';";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_query) or die('query failed'. mysqli_error($link));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       $dbUserName= $row['username'];
       $dbPassword= $row['password'];


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, 

if($myusername==$dbUserName && $mypassword==$dbPassword){

// Register $myusername, and redirect to file "login_success.php"
//session_register("myusername"); <- deprecated 

$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;

header("location:protectedstuff.php");
}else {
echo $errorLogin;
}
}
?>

<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

the usernames and passwords are already in the database.

This is my protectedstuff.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
{
    header("location:login.php");   
}

else{
?>
<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use bind parameters! http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: with the provided login details did you check if the query returned any results ?

Comment: what do you mean?  `$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_query) or die('query failed'. mysqli_error($link));` then I store the username and password form the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a `session_start()` above your `$_POST` block. You must call that on every page BEFORE any output is sent

Comment: it worked! :) in my login.php i forgot to include session_start() before $_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;

Comment: You need to add session_start() in your login.php page as you are trying to assign a value to the session variable without starting a session